# "Private" variable in namespace scope in cpp file

Tags: c++

In a source file (not a header file), I have the habit of placing some state that only the implementation can work with:

```
//.cpp

namespace foo{

   someType bar;

   //... functions and objects that might use bar ...

}
```

Because `bar` is declared only in this cpp file, it is not possible for other code files to use it, correct?

Note, however, I have not placed `static` before it. In this case, though, that should make no difference?

Without `static`, is the only difference that this variable could be accessed (and actually set) by another code file if in some other file -- either header or cpp -- I had an `extern` declaration for the same variable name? (and of course, that this declaration was within a namespace of the same name)

Since I do not have any such `extern` declaration anywhere else in the code base, I gather that it makes no difference whether I mark this as `static` or not -- but I wanted to make sure that my thinking is correct.

Comment: For module "private" variables in c++ use anonymous (unnamed) namespaces.

Comment: If you're employing global mutable state, only declaring it in one file is not really gonna help you. Just make it not global and the problem goes away.

Comment: @Puppy I am trying to *not* have global mutable state, but rather, state isolated to my implementation of a single TU.

Comment: @johnbakers: If it's not in a class or a function, it's global. The fact that it's limited to one TU does not change that. It just makes it very slightly less shit, instead of just not shit at all.

Comment: @Puppy if it's in a namespace, then technically it is "global" in the scope of the namespace, not in the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, `static` on variables in namespace scope controls only the visibility of the variable from other translation units (internal vs. external *linkage*). Apart from that, the behavior of the variable is going to remain the same. For example, it *storage class* would remain static. The only difference is that without `static` a declaration

```
namespace foo{
    extern someType bar;
    ...
}
```

from some other translation unit is going to "connect" to your `bar` variable, while with `static` the `extern` would fail at linking time.

Comment: And extern is the default declaration, right? You don't actually need to right it?